# Trying to use android mic on pc

Tags: sound, kubuntu, alsa, android, microphone

I recently started using Kubuntu 20.04 and i'm trying to use an app i used on windows called [WO Mic](https://wolicheng.com/womic/wo_mic_linux.html) but when I run it, the input device shows up, it connects but the microphone is silent.
Here's what the terminal shows:

> ~$ modprobe snd-aloop
>
> ~$ ./micclient.AppImage -t wifi 192.168.100.98
>
> Connecting...
>
> Connected

One time it showed `ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1089:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave`

Do you guys know how to fix this or any alternative for this app?

Comment: Did you try running the modprobe command with sudo as per the instructions? If so, can you edit your question to reflect this please?